# How to format output so that it output in sentence?

Tags: sql, oracle

Write the SQL to retrieve to retrieve for each appliance submitted for repair its serial number, description, date of sale,  the name of the customer who requested the repair, the description of the repair plus the cost of the repair.  (JOIN to two tables required).

Format the output so that it is output in sentences as follows:

> "The repair to appliance 9001 DVD Player,  sold on 1ST JANUARY 2018 to A.GREEN, to solve the issue DVD  Stuck  will cost €67.50".

Ensure that zeros are output if no decimal value exists.

not sure what to use to format the output..searched dbms and print but i'm not really sure if that is what the question is asking for. thanksin advance!

Customer table

```
CUSTID | CUSTNAME | CUSTPHONE | CUSTEMAIL
1001     Aaa        0123        GReen@mail.com
1002     BBB        0121        bbb@mail.com 
1003     CCCC       0333        ccc@mail.com
```

appRepair table

```
serialNO | RepairDate| RepairDesc| repairCost | Customer_ID
9001       4-Mar-18       0123        67.5          1001
9002       4-JUN-18       0121        60.7          1002
9003       4-AUG-18       0333        102.5         1003
```

appliance table

```
serialNO |    appDESC     | APPSALEDATE | GUARENTEELENGTH 
9001       DVD PLAYER       1-jan-18          2         
9002       FRIDGE FREEZER   3-may-18          5         
9003       48 TV            5-jun-18          2
```

My code for the select query

```
select appliance.serialNo, appliance.appDesc, TO_CHAR(appliance.appSaleDate, 'DDTH MONTH YY') AS "SALE DATE", 
UPPER(Customer.custName) AS "CUSTOMER NAME", Customer.custEmail from appliance 
inner join appRepair ON appliance.serialNo=appRepair.serialNo
inner join Customer ON appRepair.customer_id=Customer.custID;
```

expected output :

> "The repair to appliance 9001 DVD Player,  sold on 1ST JANUARY 2018 to A.GREEN, to solve the issue DVD  Stuck  will cost €67.50".

Comment: Hi @justforfun for this homework that you have, you have written that you need to show, among other things, > the description of the repair plus the cost of the repair 
Please can you share with us which tables are this columns from , because in your query example you do not mention them? Thanks!

Comment: just added them! :)

Comment: Great ! And your goal is to get this : "The repair to appliance 9001 DVD Player, sold on 1ST JANUARY 2018 to A.GREEN, to solve the issue DVD Stuck will cost €67.50" from this tables ?

Comment: Yeap! exactly and ensuring zeros are output if no decimal values exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is something like this:

```
     select 'The repair to appliance ' 
           || appliance.serialNo 
           || ' ' || appliance.appDesc 
           || ', sold on ' 
           || LTRIM(to_char(appliance.appSaleDate,'ddth Month YYYY','NLS_DATE_language=American'), 0)
           || ' to ' || UPPER(Customer.custName) 
           || ', to solve the issue' 
           || appRepair.RepairDesc || ' will cost ' 
           || ltrim(to_char(appRepair.repairCost, 'L9990.99'))
    from appliance 
    inner join appRepair ON appliance.serialNo = appRepair.serialNo
    inner join Customer ON appRepair.customer_id = Customer.custID;
```

This will resolve the date format:

```
select LTRIM(to_char(sysdate,'ddth Month YYYY','NLS_DATE_language=American'), 0) 
from dual;
```

And this should resolve the number format:

```
select to_char(00.00, 'L990.99') 
from dual;
```

I do not have your tables but if there is any kind of error let me know and I will try to help. Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=89cc6740ad94456e58590ed10c561761) for this so you can see how date and number formatting is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use such query containing multiple concatenations :

```
select 'The repair to appliance '||a.serialNo||' '||a.appDesc||
       ', sold on '||to_char(a.appSaleDate, 'DDTH MONTH RRRR')||
       ' to '||upper(substr(c.custEmail,1,instr(c.custEmail,'@')-1))||
       ' to solve the issue '||substr(a.appDesc,1,instr(a.appDesc,' ')-1)||
       ' Stuck will cost '|| 
         ltrim(to_char(repairCost, 'U999G999D00',
                       'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY=EUR'))
        as "Output"
  from appliance a
  join appRepair ar on a.serialNo=ar.serialNo
  join customer c on ar.customer_id=c.custID;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e2b28137b220914a4e1091ee8e8d6a77)</kbd>

If your `NLS_CHARACTERSET` DB parameter is `WE8ISO8859P1`,  then you can replace the last part of the `Output` column with

```
' Stuck will cost '||unistr('\20AC')|| 
             ltrim(to_char(repairCost, '999G999D00',
                           'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'''))
```

to be able to see the euro currency symbol.

Comment: i got an error with the query, ORA-00904: "A"."SALEDATE": invalid identifier

edit: nevermind i got it to work!

Comment: Because, there's a confusion between `appSaleDate` and `SaleDate` of `appliance` table in the question, I preferred one of them @justforfun .

Answer (score 0):

You construct it with `concat()`/`||` or replace.  Here are examples:

```
select (case when count(*) <> 1
             then 'There are ' || count(*) ' rows in the table'
             else 'There is ' || count(*) ' row in the table'
        end)
from t;
```

Or:

```
select replace(replace(replace('There [tobe] [cnt] row[plural] in the table'),
                               '[tobe]',
                               (case when count(*) = 1 then 'is' else 'are' end)
                              ), '[cnt]', count(*)

                       ), [plural], (case when count(*) = 1 then '' else 's' end)
                end)
```

I'll let you adapt this to your particular data.

Comment: select appliance.serialNo, appliance.appDesc, TO_CHAR(appliance.appSaleDate, 'DDTH MONTH YY') AS "SALE DATE", 
UPPER(Customer.custName) AS "CUSTOMER NAME", Customer.custEmail from appliance 
inner join appRepair ON appliance.serialNo=appRepair.serialNo
inner join Customer ON appRepair.customer_id=Customer.custID
(case 
when count(*) <> 1 
then 'There are ' || count(*) ' rows in the table'
else 'There is ' || count(*) ' row in the table'
end); 

is this right? i'm kinda confused on how to immplement it, im getting ORA-00905: missing keyword error